# Aren't discussions on Meta often opinion-based to a certain degree?

Tags: discussion, meta

From the tag excerpt of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion):

> A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion.

It seems odd to me then to close such questions as "primarily opinion-based".

An example is [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late), this post has/had a close/reopen war going on. I've only read a part of the answers, but I don't understand why a discussion can be closed for being opinion-based.

Comment: Yes, such questions should *absolutely* stay open. It looks as if someone doesn't like uncomfortable discussions, or something.

Comment: The whole **point** of meta is to have discussions about opinions. How else are we going to form a consensus?

Comment: There's a difference between a discussion and a shouting match.  That question's title is clearly borderline rant/opinion-based.  How would one even measure negativity in any reasonably objective way?  Given its current locked status, whether it's open or closed is largely irrelevant.

Comment: And, FWIW, the question is answered, in its entirety, here: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html.  **tl;dr:** there's an etiquette for answering questions, which most new users do not know and do not follow, and this aggravates the regulars, who rightly interpret it as laziness.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Just to be clear, I'm not in any way taking a stance here on the question.

Comment: Fair enough.  And yet, here I am, offering what I believe to be a more or less definitive answer, that will fit in a comment, on a question that attracted 64 answers and probably a hundred thousand words.  The question itself has **seventy-five moderator-deleted comments.**  It's hard to see how that kind of "discussion" is productive.

Comment: In any case, the question you refer to was linked by Reddit and Hacker news. It assumed the aerodynamic properties of a flying toaster shortly thereafter. This is what happens when you get a bunch of outsiders involved that have no skin in the game.

Comment: The moderator lock choice is funny: 'historical reasons' on a post < 1 month old!

Comment: I asked first. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250877/arent-all-feature-requests-opinion-based But close that one as a dup of this.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know how much traffic came from outside SE to that question @Robert. I can only find a few tiny threads on Reddit [1](http://www.reddit.com/r/hackernews/comments/240rsu/lots_of_hate_going_on_at_stack_overflow/), [2](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/23raqy/why_is_stack_overflow_so_negative_of_late_why_do/), [3](http://www.reddit.com/r/MetaTrueReddit/comments/2413cx/why_is_stack_overflow_so_negative_of_late/) and the one on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7650799) is tiny by comparison to the MSO post... not that it changes the outcome much.

Answer (score 9):

It's important to separate a question that is *subjective* from a question that is asking for *opinions*.

Meta is all about *subjective* questions.  There is no one single objectively correct answer to most discussion questions.

That is not to say that most meta questions are all about *opinions*.  An opinion contains no facts or references, doesn't reason about the consequences of an action, doesn't provide evidence, etc.  An opinion is generally not very useful to most meta questions.

Hearing someone say, "I think that this question shouldn't be closed" is not productive.  Hearing someone say, "Because of Foo, and having observed Baz and Bar, I believe that the site will be better off if this question isn't closed." *is* productive, and *does* help the site.

So when a meta question is phrased in such a way that it leads people to provide evidence, facts, and to reason about such evidence, even if the interpretations are open to interpretation and cannot be objectively analyzed as correct or incorrect, they are productive.  When a meta question discourages, or doesn't enable, facts, expertise, evidence, etc. and encourages users to *only* state their personal opinions, they aren't useful or productive questions.

This is all discussed in the blog post [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) as well, which has some good examples.  This blog post discusses expertise about topics such as programming and parenting.  On meta questions should be surrounding expertise on the process of running an SE site.

---

Now as for the example, I'd say that the given example is *not* a question that encourages asking only opinion.  People are providing facts, evidence, and reasoned arguments in their answers.

I could see it being "too broad" though.  The dozens of answers is actually a pretty strong indication of that...

Comment: It's a good answer, but all you really had to say was the fifth paragraph.