# Is there a negative cultural bias against of low-rep members?

Tags: discussion, reputation, upvotes

Digging deep, I feel that I use a member's reputation against them when deciding whether or not it's worth giving them an upvote. It's probably some machine-learned crap in my brain that get's worse the more I use SO.

Do others find this to be true? Or am I the only ass here?

Comment: I'm sure you aren't the *only* ass here. The first step is to admit you have a problem. Next, try to be more objective.

Comment: The bias should be towards **bad and off-topic** content. That it appears to correlate with new users is a different matter.

Comment: I don't have a bias with my upvotes, but if a HIGH rep user (e.g. anyone who clearly knows the site) posts something sub-par they'll certainly see a downvote from me, where a low rep user might just about have got away with it.

Comment: The topic of people voting based on reputation has been discussed extensively on MSE. [The problem with reputation: does high reputation attract too many upvotes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/515) (+ the 33 linked questions)

Comment: As it's currently presented, I don't see this question as being productive and constructive. It offers personal experience, rather than fact and number based evidence. Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Every SO user was once a low-rep user.  The ones you should have low expectations for are the ones that have been stuck at it for years.

Comment: I'm occasionally very pleased to see a user with barely any reputation post very well reasoned, knowledgeable answers. I usually check their profile to see if they just joined and what else they're posting, and am happy to supply upvotes.

Comment: "Primarily opinion-based" is a dodgy close reason for Meta.

Comment: @dilbert there's actually been discussion about that, if not already here on Meta, then in posts on [meta.se]. Basically, questions that aren't backed up with evidence, and that don't provide a framework that leads to a constructive solution, may be closed as "non-constructive".

Comment: @dilbert ah, here's one discussion about it, see [Aren't discussions on Meta often opinion-based to a certain degree?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255156/456814).

Comment: @Cupcake, I wasn't aware of that other thread; thanks for that. As for questions being "evidence based", that's only meaningful in the context of objective truth. Questions about culture cannot be objectively resolved using a SQL query, as that data would have to be *subjectively* interpreted anyway. The only way to discover, in this case, is to ask the question. I don't see how closing the question helps the discussion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what happens to my brain on newbies:

1. "Halp, my code doesn't werk."
2. "i'm posting from an old cell phone that doesn't know i is capitalized."
3. Thinks I am clairvoyant, or can somehow divine why his code is crashing without so much as looking at a line of code or an error message... "Anyone else have this problem?"
4. Thinks I am an ideas man... "Any idea?"

And then... I look at his rep.

Comment: But do you have any ideas? Please sir, I want some more.

Comment: +1 for calling out the "Any ideas?" antipattern. It's a lazy crutch used to cover up when the asker isn't really sure what their question is.

Answer (score 2):

I most situations, first impressions count a lot, and it would be strange if that wasn't true for Stack Overflow, too.

For me, first impressions on SO are formed by:

First, the title. I use the from page a lot, which only shows the title of the question, not the text. The user's rep is has a very discreet position and often relates to who last edited something on the page.

Second, after clicking the question, by the look of the post. Is it one big unstructured hunk of text or is it divided into sentences that I can identify (capital letters, full stops, etc.) and has the poster taken the time to divide it into a few paragraphs? And if there is code, I immediately notice if it formatted so it looks good and is readable.

Third, I read the first paragraph. Does it sound like someone who can ask a question and understand the answer or does it give the impression of someone who babbles incoherently about something they don't really understand?

Fourth - I take a quick look at the code. Did they take the time (and did they have the skills) to pick out the 10 lines or so that contain the problem, or have they dumped the whole file on the poor reader (me!) to sort it out?

At this point I have already decided what I think about the question, and by extension, the poster, and I haven't even looked at the rep yet.